# How to mock octokit.rest.repos.getContent()

Tags: typescript, octokit, octokit-js

How can I mock octokit library in jest

```
import { Octokit } from '@octokit/rest';
```

The code I'm using is:

```
const { data: entity } = await octokit.rest.repos.getContent({owner, repo, path, ref})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do it, it is my preferred way (Disclaimer: I created most of the JavaScript Octokit).

When you instantiate Octokit, you can pass a custom `fetch` implementation

```
const octokit = new Octokit({ request: { fetch } })
```

Create the `fetch` instance using https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock.

Here is an example: https://github.com/octokit/core.js/blob/5ffb0f86acecf137e195befae505147e08e08fe4/test/request.test.ts